# How to determine which numbers lie within a certain range

Tags: pari, pari-gp

I currently have a list of numbers, and I want to know which of these numbers are within a certain range, and what their position is in the list.

I'm reasonably new to pari so I'm not sure how exactly to go about this.

For a simplistic example of what I'm doing:

> Find the inverses of the numbers 1 to 20 which lie within the range 0.05 and 0.15

I've set up a list like this:

```
A=[1/i|i<-[1..20]];
```

From here, I'd like a list of all the i so that A[i] is in that range.

But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. I tried some simple if/for statements, but these weren't working.

How exactly would I try and go about something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `select`:
Either:

```
select(i->A[i]>=0.05 && A[i]<=0.15, [1..#A])
```

Or more compactly using the flag 1 to return indices:

```
select(v->v>=0.05 && v<=0.15, A, 1)
```